# gojs textblock is cut

Tags: textblock, gojs

I add a textblock. In order to wrap it with margin, I write this code.
The problem is that now the text is cut.
code:

```
       let $ = go.GraphObject.make;
       let toolTipTemplate =
           $(go.Adornment, "Auto",
               $(go.Shape, { fill: "#FFFFCC" }),
               $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 4 },
                   new go.Binding("text", "", (d) => {
                          return d.model.Name + "\nsome text here";
                   }))
           );
       return toolTipTemplate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a node template like:

```
      $(go.Node, . . .,
        {
          toolTip: $(go.Adornment, "Auto",
                $(go.Shape, { fill: "#FFFFCC" }),
                $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 4 },
                    new go.Binding("text", "", (d) => {
                     return d.text + "\ncatalog: " + d.name;
                    }))
            )
        },
        . . .
```

And I was unable to reproduce any problem with a very long string as the property value of data.name.  Do you know of a way for me to reproduce this text measurement problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with this style definition:
`letter-spacing: 3px;`
so, the text became too wide.
After removing this setting it looks right.